# Min and Max length of a varchar in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to set a minimum length for a `varchar(25)` field in Postgres?

So that I can prevent from accidentally adding invalid values during manual insert?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do that using a check constraint:

```
alter table the_table
  add constraint check_min_length check (length(the_column) >= 10);
```

You probably also want to define the column as `not null`

Comment: I know this is an old answer but i wonder if you can help - this also seems to prevent changes to existing rows where the length is too short, is there a way to only make it apply to updates to the value / new entries?

Comment: @JonathanPlackett I am not the person you replied to, but I think you could use a trigger function for that, which only triggers on INSERT and UPDATE. [Here are some good examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE).

Comment: Hi - thanks, triggers is the thing I needed here!